# ClearKey decryption is not working in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer, drm, mpeg-dash

I'm trying to DASH stream an encrypted file using ClearKey DRM in Android ExoPlayer. Details of entry added in `media.exolist.json` are given below:

```
{
        "name": "ClearKey",
        "uri": "https://drmdemo-94ea7.firebaseapp.com/encrypt/manifest.mpd",
        "extension": "mpd",
        "drm_scheme": "cenc",
        "drm_license_url": "https://drmdemo-94ea7.firebaseapp.com/encrypt/key.json"
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting

```
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Media does not support uuid: 1077efec-c0b2-4d02-ace3-3c1e52e2fb4b
```

Can anyone help me out with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is ExoPlayer telling you that it cannot find the DRM scheme indicated by the UUID in the media PSSH header:

```js
schemePsshData = psshData.get(uuid);
      if (schemePsshData == null) {
        onError(new IllegalStateException("Media does not support uuid: " + uuid));
        return;
      }
```

The DRM information can be included in the manifest and/or the media file itself. In the media file it will be in the Protection System Specific Header (PSSH).

UUID's are just a unique identifier for each different protection systems (e.g for different DRMs).

For your case it appears that the media file (the video file or stream itself) does not have the expected DRM information in its PSSH header.